# What is the font the battery percentage uses?

Tags: macos, battery, font

A bit of a stupid question, but what is the font the battery percentage (pictured below) in OS X uses?

[image: 82]

It is **not** the standard font you can get by calling `[NSFont menuBarFontOfSize:0]`, I have noticed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very likely to be Lucida Grande 13pt (It's the system default font).